# where does debrelease put the package?

Tags: debian, packages

I use debrealse command to setup my package. But I cannot find it on disk. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

`debrelease` doesn't set up a package.  It uploads a package using either `dput` or `dupload`.  The output should tell you where it is uploading to.  But I guess if you haven't actually set that up, it won't be uploading anything.